# How to stop the animation when required and start it immediately in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I need help.

I want my image which is falling from the top of screen to get invisible when I click a button on the keyboard which has the same tag as the image. Although I have implemented the above points a problem arises when I want to show the next animation again immediately after the previous image gets invisible. This is my code for animation.

```
public void startAnimation(final ImageView aniView) 
{

    animator= ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0 ,.85f);
    animator.setDuration(Constants.ANIM_DURATION);
    animator.setInterpolator(null);

    //generation of random values
    Random rand = new Random();
    index = rand.nextInt((int) metrics.widthPixels);
    //for debugging
    i = Integer.toString(index);
    Log.e(" index is :", i);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener()
    {       




        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
        {
            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();

            aniView.setTranslationX(index);

            aniView.setTranslationY((height+ (50*mScale))*value);
            //aniView.setTranslationY(height);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}

//keyboard methods goes here

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    gettext(v);
}

private void gettext(View v)
{
    try
    {
        String b = "";
        b = (String) v.getTag();

        String img_val = map.get(b);
        int  imgid = (Integer) imageView.getTag();

        Log.e("img values=:", img_val+"  "+imgid);
        if(img_val.equals(ALPHABETS[imgid]))
        {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            animator.start();
            //trying to start the animation again 
        }
```

I am using the animation.addupdateListener to call the animation again and again but it only calls when the *.ofFloat* finishes on the value. When I click on the appropriate button the animation gets invisible but the next animation starts again after the same time. I want to start it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Basically calling start() again won't work. you need to "reset" the animation somehow, did you try calling end() before ?

```
animator.end();
animator.start();
```